# Google analytics - allowed hosts

Tags: google-analytics

I'm seeing entries in my analytics data for pages that no longer exist.

This could be developers looking at legacy versions of a site, it could also be triggered by something like wayback machine.

Is there a way to either identify what hosts an analytics tracking pixel is being triggered on, or restrict analytics to only execute on either a set of domains/hosts or ip address

LinkedIn campaign manager and Hubspot have features where you can tell the tracking script what domains to include/exclude

This is different from excluding ip addresses when setting up filters

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use filters on view level (Universal Analytics, not GA4) in order to exclude or include specified domains to ga data. Keep in mind, adding or removing filters work for new collected data only. Maybe add an additional view, so one view contains all data (based on your ga setup). With this solution GA collects data but will not show the data in the filtered view.

[image]

In order to fire the ga tag on a specified domain, specify the host in the trigger in Google Tag Manager, if it is implemented on page. This setting the tag will not be fired on other domains.

[image]

If there is no Tag Management on the page, you can check the domain using js before firing the ga script.

Keep in mind, that it is possible to send data to GA without fireing the GA tag by using Measurement Protocol. So if a lot of spam data appears in the interface, may add additional filters to exclude this data aswell.